# html css full screen banner image transparent menubar

Tags: html, css, header

[Please see the sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrLgI.png)

hello,
here I m trying to code the full-screen background banner image, I tried to like this
I cant active the best result, how i can make the background image or gradient like the sample image. if i give the bg color to the header tag is it good? or to the section tag class? if to the section class how can shift the bg to top and behind the menu bar ?
someone please help me guide me. thank you.

```
<header>
<nav> <div class="container">
        <div>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li ><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li ><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div> </nav>
</header>
<section class="home-banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="home-banner-text">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing Aliquamum 
                        sem integer mi facilisi fringilla odio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="full-bg-img">
                    <img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    .home-banner {
width: 100%;
height: 1106px;
background: #0E0E0E;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
display: flex;
align-items: center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with this css you can do the fix

```
.home-banner {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #0E0E0E url('YOUR IMAGE URL HERE') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You can add all the background settings into the `background` attribute and then specify your `background-size`.

Hope this is what you need. If it is not, please com back with more information.